# Pressing Enter to choose a suggestion in VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have installed VScode recently. I loved it alot but I have a problem with it. When I writer a code (for example, an HTML5 code) and writes an opening tag like `<form>`, it appears in a list of suggestions as shown below. When I hit enter on the suggestion `form` I expect that an automatic closing tag (`</form>`) will be placed. But, what is really going is that the word in the opening tag is completed and the ending angular bracket of the opening tag is not placed and that the closing tag is not placed as well. Is there a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: If you type the `>` it will automatically place the closing tag `</form>`

Comment: don't type the `<` but use Emmet, just type `form`

Comment: This works very well. Thank you @rioV8

Comment: read the emmet doc to see what other constructs you can type to speed the generation of tags with classes and ids, it also works in CSS, Pug, ....